# Spring Boot thin layout with spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot project with Spring Data JPA and it's working fine with the uber jar package.

When create a thin jar or configure manually the MANIFEST.mf to have the dependencies in a custom lib folder, I get the following error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [com/br/vrsoftware/vranalyticsapi/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence
>   unit root URL

That's what I've tried in my pom.xml

Using Thin Layout:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-thin-layout</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.11.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <configuration>
            <executable>true</executable>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Generating custom MANIFEST.mf:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-thin-layout</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.11.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
        <executable>true</executable>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                <mainClass>com.br.vrsoftware.vranalyticsapi.VrAnalyticsApiApplication</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And here is my database configuration class

```java
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;

@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.br.vrsoftware.vranalyticsapi.model"});
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);

        JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        factoryBean.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());


        return factoryBean;

    }

    private Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        props.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        props.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @Profile("producao")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder
                .create()
                .username("postgres")
                .password("postgres")
                .url("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/vranalytics")
                .driverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver")
                .build();
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciate

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44312643/getting-unable-to-resolve-persistence-unit-error-when-building-jar-without-ide

Comment: I have tried this workaround without any success. I'm using version 2.0.3 of spring boot.

Comment: Why a Thin layout but package the dependencies? That doesn’t sound right. Also you shouldn’t be overriding the mainClass as spring boot actually uses a different attribute for that. So basically you are disallowing with your custom manifest spring boot to properly start. Also you seem to fight with the framework instead of using it. You are trying to workaround the spring boot plugin which does all the packaging required for Spring Boot but still expect it to work.

Comment: I don't want the uber jar because we'll have some other dependencies of ours that might be updated on the fly in our costumers. If we need to update those dependencies we wanna just replace the dependency and not the whole app. That's why I want all the libs and dependencies to not be packed into jar. Those XML above I've tried separately but none seems to work for me.
Just let me know I there is another approach for me.