# Spring-boot app working in IDEA but crash when running jar - “Unable to resolve persistence unit"

Tags: spring, scala, hibernate, jakarta-ee

**Updated**: 
It's been days that I tried to accomodate some times in between then came back to this code-base, but still faced up the same issue.

I am frustrated that have a Spring Boot 1.5.12 application that worked in IDEA but failed when running executable jar in Unix box, and the stack trace follows this format that I needed to trim the stack trace for relevancy:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'xxxEntityManager' defined in class path resource [com.abc.persistence.ConfigClass]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL
................. [Skipped the stack strace]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:187) 
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.determineDefaultPersistenceUnitRootUrl(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:602) 
        ... 48 common frames omitted
```

As per suggestion by [Getting "Unable to resolve persistence unit" error when building jar without IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44312643/getting-unable-to-resolve-persistence-unit-error-when-building-jar-without-ide), I tried this workaround of 2 changes but it doesn't work at all.

```
1)@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class) to my application class

2)spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=false to my application.yml file in src/main/resource/ directory
```

Even with those two changes being added, it still shows the same error.

I hope someone can help me figure out this frustrating inconsistency occured between the run time behavior in IDEA and executable jar in console.

**Edit**:
I used Gradle build script with this build task *applications* to build the app jar executable whose jar pull everything of src files in package names and resource property configuration yaml files besides gradle build:

```
applications {
...
}
```

So I've been tried to crack the root cause that runs my life nuts, which is based on this possible mystery:

Can someone know about jar (JVM) process of how it processes to create jar artifacts that in the end when I face the extremely weird anomaly *where Intellj has always been able to set the persistence unit URL to default*,   whereas *running on jar doesn't accomodate this auto-configuration already coded in the app and property codes*?

Comment: How did you generate the jar?

Comment: I used the gradle to generate the jar to another directory beside src/ directory, where it store app runningpath jar file and its corresponding exec file if I remembered correctly.